# Sygic Custom URL IOS

Tags: custom-url, sygic, url-launcher

i have been using an url launch that open sygic and drives to coordinates n my website.
It looks like this: com.sygic.aura://coordinate|15.06591|47.73341|drive

After the last Sygic update this url launch does not work anymore, it fires up Sygic but no route is calculated any longer.
Does anybody have som ideas to overcome this?
Is there anyone else that hava this problem and found a solution for it?

This is what i tested with iPad Air 12.5.3, Sygic Version 20.4.5

All of Sygics custom url: https://www.sygic.com/developers/professional-navigation-sdk/ios/custom-url

Comment: I can confirm this issue. I just received a report about this here: https://forum.kurviger.de/t/export-the-route-to-sygic-navigation/638/11?u=boldtrn

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the Sygic Support. Here is their answer:

> Thank you for contacting Sygic.
>
> We apologize for the inconvenience. You're using the legacy format which is no longer supported in the latest release. Instead of this format, universal links can be used.
>
> For your use case, you can use:
> https://go.sygic.com/directions?to=latitude,longitude

Comment: I got the same answer from Sygic, unfortunately the new format does not work for those with Android devices. I have answered sygic if they plan to add support for the new format in android to, i got no answer at the moment for that.